# If health insurance 'doesn't cover' a procedure, does the cost of the procedure get applied to my deductible?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

If I haven't yet met my deductible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [HealthCare.gov](https://www.healthcare.gov/glossary/deductible/)  (emphasis added):

> ### Deductible
>
> The amount you pay for ***covered*** health care services before your
>   insurance plan starts to pay. With a $2,000 deductible, for example,
>   you pay the first $2,000 of ***covered*** services yourself.

So expenses that are *not* covered by your health insurance do not get applied toward your deductible (or your out-of-pocket maximum).

Comment: Just to expand on this perfectly accurate answer, all accumulators of any kind on any health plan (deductible and out of pocket but also lifetime maximums, and things like visits per year, etc) only ever include covered services. Practically, this is because covered services are the only ones that are explicitly defined by the plan. You can't really include something that you can't define.

Comment: Just to add some complexity, many plans have two different deductibles for in-network vs out-of-network.

Comment: @TTT Good point, although that applies to _providers_. Services are either covered or not; whether the service is in-network or not depends on the provider (it's irrelevant for an uncovered service). Not refuting you, just distinguishing the two.

Comment: @DStanley - I agree. It's not relevant to the question. I only mentioned it because covered services may have more than 1 deductible. It's probably not relevant for the answer either. :)